# React error process is not defined. how we resolved it ? @carbon/ibmdotcom-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, process

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcyoI.png)

process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined
at ./node_modules/@carbon/ibmdotcom-react/es/internal/vendor/@carbon/ibmdotcom-services/services/Analytics/Analytics.js (http://localhost:5000/static/js/bundle.js:35425:22)

"@carbon/grid": "^10.20.0",
"@carbon/ibmdotcom-react": "^1.12.0",
"@carbon/ibmdotcom-styles": "^1.10.1",
"@carbon/pictograms-react": "^10.10.0",
"@carbon/themes": "^10.34.0",
"@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.2.0",
"@ibm/plex": "^5.1.0",
"postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
"react": "16.14.0",
"react-csv": "^2.0.3",
"react-dom": "16.14.0",
"react-i18next": "^11.8.7",
"react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.4",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",

"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.10.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
"css-loader": "^4.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.2",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.2",
"prettier": "^2.1.1",
"process": "^0.11.10",
"querystring": "npm:querystring-es3@0.2.1",
"react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
"sass-loader": "10.0.2",
"stream": "npm:stream-browserify@3.0.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.2.0"
},

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.